# How to push messages from my server in PHP to Android device?

Tags: php, push, message

I want to push messages from my cloud server to Android emulator or Android device with phone number.

Is it possible? Do I need to use any gateway?

Comment: Do you want to send push notifications or sms messages?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Basically you would have to make CURL call to

https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Something like this:

```
$data = array(
        'collapse_key' => $msgType,
        'data' => array('message' => $news_text,
                'title' => $news_title,
                'url' => $messageUrl,
                'message_id' => $news_id,
                'notification_type' => $channel_name),
        'registration_ids' => $devices
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
if ($headers)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

$response_json = curl_exec($ch);


$response = json_decode($response_json);

print_r($response_json);
```

Comment: I dont want to use GCM!

Comment: is there any other way to send push notifications from PHP file(cloud server)>???

Comment: because GCM itself is a cloud.....here i made a cloud where it will push message as it will recieve the message!

Answer (score 0):

GCM / FCM is the goto solution. If every   app which uses push notifications would implement some sort of listening or polling service the battery would drain way to fast. Thats why google and also Apple provide 1 single service for the whole Androidsystem and its apps to use.

This means that it isnt impossible todo, i think there are some third party push notifications-services.

I just dont think its a clever thing todo. Chances are that google build a reliable, fast and efficient service.